# How do I assign a string to an int variable?

Tags: c++, converters

I'm making a Card and Deck program and I am a bit confused on how to implement a feature in the constructor to make the Card Rank equal to "Ace" "Jack" "King" "Queen" etc. depending on the number.

```
Card::Card(char suiter, int ranker) {
    suit = suiter;
    rank = ranker;
    if (rank == 1) {
        rank = "Ace";   //Assign rank to "Ace" if the number equals 1
    }
}
```

Comment: How `"Ace"` can be a number to assign to an int?

Comment: You can not assign a string to an int.

Comment: Yea sorry.. I'm fairly new to coding. I'm just not sure how to deal with such a problem. Assigning "Ace" to rank may not be the proper way of doing it, that is why I am asking the question.

Comment: How about taking a string variable instead?

Comment: Then you can assign both "4"(number) and "ace"(string)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you much!

Comment: somebody post `std::variant` as a joke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to do such in the constructor. Instead you can change the output of the ostream when the rank values equal specific numbers. For instance:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const Card &rhs) {   
    if (rhs.rank == 1) {
                out << "Ace of ";
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an enum. This is not literally a string, but rather a set of constant ints which are guaranteed to not share values.

```
enum CardRank
{
  Ace,
  Two,
... ... ...
  Jack,
  Queen,
  King
};
```

This creates a new type `CardRank` that you can use just for card ranks within your code. You just make your `rank` member be of type `CardRank` and you can refer to its value by name.

Under the hood, this is, for most intents and purposes, an unsigned int that can only accept values ranging from `Ace` (0) through `King` (12)

Given that I don't see that you are trying to write this string to the screen, this might be the way to go. And even if you *are* planning to write this string out, you might want to use this enum anyway and only pull out the string meaning when you need to write it with a lookup like this:

```
std::string RankNames[] =
{
  "Ace",
  "2",
... ... ... ...
  "Jack",
  "Queen",
  "King"
};

CardRank rank = Ace;

std::cout << RankNames[rank] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use rank as i int and next as i string type. If you wanna create something like that, try to use a string type for rank. 
ho